# VSCode Intellisense not fully working in commonjs files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, realm, svelte, vite

I am using the `realm-web` sdk to access the mongodb backend system from my svelte application. I need to initialize a new realm-app, so i created a global `realm.cjs` file for it:

```js
import * as Realm from "realm-web";

const app = new Realm.App({ id: "myrandomid" });

export default {
    app
}
```

I try to use it in my svelte components like this:

```html
<script>
   import app from '../lib/realm.cjs'
</script>
```

But the IntelliSense from VSCode is not working. When i try to access functions from the `app` object inside the `realm.cjs` file it works. What do i need to change, to get this working?

Note: I am using svelte with vite.js

Comment: You cannot use cjs code in the browser, it does not understand that. Use ES module syntax instead.